Token 2022 Program: FreezeAccount (Program Error: "Invalid account state for operation")
I bought YUKI tokens and got this message when I tried to sell them,
"Token 2022 Program: FreezeAccount
(Program Error: "Invalid account state for operation")"
what do I do to get them unfrozen or who and how do I contact the program owner to get them unfrozen?

You'll need to ask the YUKI token creator. It looks like they froze your tokens
